# How to remove ‘Add New’ button from Admin Grid in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, widget

I am trying to remove the Add New button from an Adminhtml grid in Magento 1.9.

I have found [this post](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-remove-or-rename-add-new-button-from-admin-grid/) and [this other one]
([Magento 2 - How to remove "Add new MODEL" button on \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166711/magento-2-how-to-remove-add-new-model-button-on-magento-backend-block-widge)) about doing that in Magento 2.0, but the same technique does not apply to Magento 1.9.

The error reported in Magento 1.9 is this:

```
exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method TBF_Cupom_Block_Adminhtml_Gerados_Index_Grid::_removeButton(Array
(
    [0] => add
)
)' in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Object.php:653
```

In fact it makes sense because Grid's parent class is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and it does not have a `_removeButton()` method.

So, the question remains... How can I remove the Add New button from an Admin Grid Widget in Magento 1.9?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ` $this->_removeButton('add');` is available in grid container class not in grid class

Answer (score 7):

Renate, if you are following the [tutorial](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified), then you'll need to add the code suggested by Rama to this section

```
<?php
class Foo_Bar_Block_Adminhtml_Baz extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    // The blockGroup must match the first half of how we call the block, and controller matches the second half
    // ie. foo_bar/adminhtml_baz
        $this->_blockGroup = 'foo_bar';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_baz';
        $this->_headerText = $this->__('Baz');

        parent::__construct();

        // must be placed after the parent::__construct();
        $this->_removeButton('add');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try like this

```
TBF_Cupom_Block_Adminhtml_Gerados_Index extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

 public function __construct()
    {
.....
 $this->_removeButton('add');
}
}
```

**Note:** `_removeButton()`  is not in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid`  it is in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container` . call proper extends or proper class need to call.

Comment: Thank you @rama for the reply but it didn't work. Now the page shows 2 headers. The first one still contains the Add New button. And the second header displays Back, Reset and Save buttons. Further more on the content section appears this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php on line 147` -- here is a [link](https://pastebin.com/k0EUpSuU) to my code

Comment: I think you are something is missing in your form. please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138462/error-when-creating-an-edit-block-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setdat

Comment: Please provide your entire module code here i will check :)

Comment: It is not a Form, is a list Grid. I am following to the letter this tutorial [here](http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified). Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, In your block;

```
protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->buttonList->remove('add');
    }
```